# how to access svn repository over internet

Tags: svn, repository

Hi i have set up svn repository and i was to access it over internet.
i have done in svn dir...

```
svnserve -d -r path
```

but it says

```
[~/svnrepo]# svnserve -d -r /home2/alohamor/svnrepo/
svnserve: Can't bind server socket: Address already in use
```

Pls help what to do

Answer (score 4):

Find and kill the already running svn process with:

```
ps -ef  | grep svnserve
```

Check out [this solution](http://errorbank.blogspot.com/2012/07/svnserve-cant-bind-server-socket.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

This means another program (maybe another instance of svnserve) is already using the svn port. Check `netstat -a` for applications with port 3690 open

Comment: @user453506: the app listening on TCP is your problem. There are only two kinds of socket, TCP and UPD. Svnserve uses TCP as well.

Comment: i have run the command again .. it has run but without any message and still if i ma trying to access it .. its timing out